# Authentification NodeJS Sequelize Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, authentication, sequelize.js

I'm trying implement NodeJS authentification with express, sequelize, and mysql, but i'm blocked. I get login and password values by webservice. I want to match them with database value :

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res, err) {           
    var whereUser = {
        login: req.query.login,
        password: req.query.password
    }      

    if (!req.query.login || !req.query.password) {
        res.send('login failed');
//Here my code is wrong ! 
I try to compare login and password values with database login and passwword values          
            } else if (req.query.login && req.query.password == UsrPerson.findOne({ where: whereUser })) {        
                console.log("auth ok")
                req.session.user = "amy";
                req.session.admin = true;        
                res.send("login success!");
            } else {
                console.log("ERROR")
                res.send(err)
            }
        });
```

How can I do that ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findOne` method from sequelize return an instance object of the model.
that means than you can't compare a `password` to an instance.

The second problem is the `findOne` method is asynchronous, you  need to `await` it and have an `async` method.

```
app.get('/login', async function (req, res, err) {           
    var whereUser = {
        login: req.query.login,
        password: req.query.password
    }      

   if (!req.query.login || !req.query.password) {
       res.send('login failed');
    } else {        
        // The following code return an instance of the user if it was found.
       const user = await UsrPerson.findOne({ where: whereUser }))

       // If the user was not found that means the credentials was wrong.
       if (user) {
           console.log("auth ok")
           req.session.user = "amy";
           req.session.admin = true;        
           res.send("login success!");
       } else {
           console.log("ERROR")
           res.send(err)
       }
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res, err) {    
  const { login, password } = req.query;

  UsrPerson
    .findOne({
      where: {
        login: login,
        password: password
      }
    })
    .then((foundUser) => {
      if(!foundUser){
        res.send('login failed');
      } else {
        console.log("auth ok");
        req.session.user = "amy";
        req.session.admin = true;
        res.send("login success!");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('ERROR');
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

You want to compare if the user with the given username and password combination exists.

And seems like you are storing the password without any encryption, in plain text. This is not secure at all. You have to use a library like [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) and only store the encrypted password in your database